# How to concatenate in vba

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I have approximately 100000 lines with data from different countries.
I have to format the national IDs into different formats.
Eg 123456789 should be 12.345-6789
My challenge is that if I use

```
cells(i,6).formula = "=left(SecId,3)"
```

It should be followed by &"." and so on

But this will not work.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please show your code that does not work and the error message or the wrong output.

Comment: Do you have to hardcode the formatted ID? Instead you may keep the cells as they are and format them with this string (using right click **Format Cells** menu): `##"."###-####`

Comment: Or you may use CHAR(38) instead of & character in VBA.

Comment: Why use formulas?  Why not either format it in VBA and write the result to the cell; or use Conditional Formatting to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The `&` you are providing in your code is used as concatenation operator within *VBA*, concatenating the strings `"=left(SecId,3)"` and `.`.

You want the `&` as part of the formula, so simply put it into the string. Now, *VBA* doesn't see the `&` as operator but simply as part of the string. It will then be part of the formula in the cell and *Excel* will interpret it.

```
cells(i,6).formula = "=left(SecId,3)&."
```

Of course you can use the `&` within VBA if you need to:

```
cells(i,6).formula = "=left(SecId,3)" & "&."
```

Now the first `&` is seen by *VBA* while the second one is part of a string and passed to *Excel*.